# Javascript retorna valores undefined

Tags: javascript

Obtener los valores de la propiedad país que se encuentra en varios objetos , retorna UNDEFINED

El método 'consegirPaises' debe devolver un arreglo con los países del viajero

Ejemplo:

> viajero.conseguirPaises() debe devolver ['Belgica', 'Estados Unidos']

Si tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos (si el viajero tuviera estos compañeros... todo esto forma parte de una clase):

```
       {
         compañeros: [{
           nombre: 'Juan',
           pais: "Belgica",
           edad: 27,
         }, {
           nombre: 'Pedro',
           pais: "Estados Unidos",
           edad: 23
         }]
```

He tratado de trabajar con  estos códigos pero todos me retornan un arreglo  así:

```
  [ undefined, 'Belgica', 'Estados Unidos']
```

me muestra un dato INDEFINIDO como primer dato del arreglo .

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Estos son los códigos :

codigo # 1:

```
  var arreglopaises = []; 
  var paisaingresar  ;

  for(var i = 0 ;i< this.compañeros.length; i ++){

    paisaingresar = this.compañeros[i].pais;
    arreglopaises.push(paisaingresar);
                                                 }
   return arreglopaises;
```

Codigo # 2:

```
    var arreglopaises = this.compañeros.map(function(x){     
    return x.pais;
                                                       });
    return arreglopaises;
```

Codigo # 3 :

```
        const x = ((amigo) => amigo.pais);                                                                         
        
        const arreglopaises = this.compañeros.map(x);            
        return arreglopaises ;
```

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No comprendi bien, pero entiendo que tenes un objeto viajero, que a su vez tiene compañeros. Y se debe retorar un array con los paises de los compañeros:

```
viajero = {
    compañeros: [{
        nombre: 'Juan',
        pais: "Belgica",
        edad: 27,
    }, {
        nombre: 'Pedro',
        pais: "Estados Unidos",
        edad: 23
    }],
    conseguirPaises() {
        return this.compañeros.map(function (x) {
            return x.pais;
        });
    }
}

console.log(viajero.conseguirPaises())
```

Implementando tu funcion me devuelve-> [ 'Belgica', 'Estados Unidos' ]

Podrias adjuntar el codigo completo que estas queriendo implementar?

Comment: Exactamente debe retornar un arreglo con solo los países.

Comment: La función me está devolviendo un arreglo asi [ undefined,  'Belgica', 'Estados Unidos' ] , Me muestra un primer dato indefinido en el arreglo.

Comment: El código completo lo tengo en el PC estoy desde el celular ahora, apenas tenga acceso lo comparto completo. Gracias muy amable 

Comment: Gracias ya funciona.